# How do you set a wild card in custom vim mapping?

Tags: vim

For example, I want to map the key stroke `<Fixed key><Number>` to `:tabn <Number><CR>`. I don't normally use more than 8-9 open tabs and so this will be helpful for quickly switching between tabs. How do I set the mapping to accept any entry in `<Number>`? Of course, since there are only 9 possible options, I can simply write it out for each one, but I wanted to know if there's a smarter way of doing this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question is nice, but you can already use `<number>gt` for that. And I am afraid there is no way to have argument-dependent mapping. However you could do a loop in vimscript that generates your mapping commands.

Edit: otherwise you can put that in your vimrc:

```
let i = 1
while i <= 9
  execute 'nnoremap <fixed_key>' . i . ' ' . i . 'gt'
  let i = i + 1
endwhile
```

Comment: oh, thanks. i didn't know that command. however, i'll let the question stay as I'm interested in knowing how one would do such a mapping.